# Function Pointer as a Friend Function

Tags: c++, oop, function-pointers, friend

I am using function pointers within a class to allow extendable functionality at runtime.

I have typedef'd the function signature:

```
typedef f32 generate_height(f32 x, f32 y);
```

Now, within the class I am using function pointers:

```
class TerrainChunk
{
...
private:
        generate_height *heightgen;
...
}
```

I would like this function pointer to be allowed to access private attributes of TerrainChunk. I could pass them, but different functions might need different attributes - for example, I might need to access the Mesh of the terrain in some functions, or the location of the terrain in others. So this would quickly become a very large function signature, which is neither ideal nor extensible.

I tried putting the friend keyword in different places, which did not work.

Any suggestions on how I could achieve this functionality?

Comment: It's not possible. The workaround is to pass an instance of `TerrainChunk` as an argument to the function and then use its public functions (which of course can access the private members).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I had feared as much. But that's not all that bad I guess. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make a function *pointer* a friend of `TerrainChunk`.  You can only make *functions* a friend of `TerrainChunk`.

That means you can only make a finite set of functions friends.  You can't load an arbitrary function at run-time and have it able to read the private parts of `TerrainChunk`.

As [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) suggests, the work-round is to pass a reference (or pointer) to (const) `TerrainChunk` to the function, and give `TerrainChunk` enough public accessor functions that the `generate_height` functions can obtain all the info they need.

(You can make the accessors in-line, so this won't have any performance penalty).

Comment: Thanks! This works, just a pain to write all those extra accessors :P